# Loop is not properly assigning values when reading from text file

Tags: java

So obviously I'm really new to Java and I'm trying to read a text file and put in a loop. Each iteration of the loop will read one line and assign it to a variable. I have a few methods inside my class that will help with this. However, when I assign the variables through the loop, and print them out, it prints out nothing. I've tried many different things and spent hours trying to get this to work but to no avail.
Here is my code:

```
public void readFile(File value) {
    try {
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(value);
        for (int i = 0; i == 4; i++) {
            switch(i) {
            case 0:
                setId(inputFile.nextLine());
            case 1:
                setDescription(inputFile.nextLine());
            case 2:
                setDepartment(inputFile.nextLine());
            case 3:
                setPrice(inputFile.nextLine());
            case 4:
                setLocation(inputFile.nextLine());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
//toString
public String toString() {
    return id + description + department + price + location;
}
```

}

The setId, setDesc...etc are my methods inside my class. I have a main program that calls upon these methods:

```
stringClass stringTest = new stringClass();
    File myFile = new File("readFromFile.txt");
    try {
        stringTest.readFile(myFile);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(stringTest);
```

However, when it prints, it only prints out null(which is the default value I gave to the id/description/etc variables within my default constructor. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: Your loop condition is inverted. It needs to be true for the loop to continue. `i == 4` will be false as soon as it starts, so it exits the loop immediately. I'm guessing you meant `i <= 4`, or more conventionally, `i < 5`.

Comment: Also, your `case`s are missing `break`s, meaning it'll run through all the subsequent cases.

Comment: @shmosel thanks so much. I had these in earlier iterations I did but I was rewriting so much code that I guess I forgot about these really simple things. It works now, thank you again! :)